# Ember JS custom Rest URL

Tags: rest, ember.js

I want to use custom url for rest in Ember JS. I want to use url like http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Limpbizkit
Is it possible?

Comment: are you using ember-data?

Comment: No, i'm using just ember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Since you are not using ember-data just fetch data using jQuery ajax. EvilTrout has a great blog post explaining how this can be done, check it out here:

http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

Answer (score 0):

just use Ember.$.ajax and you can issue an ajax call to your rest end point.